# UTF-8 in *.cshtml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017

I edit the text, my english is very, very... bad

Hi!!!

I have a problem with UTF-8 in Visual Studio 2017.

I work with Asp.Net Core 1.1 and need  UTF-8 in my CSHTML files.

The Some way i found to change the codification is goining in
File->Save As..->In save button, click on the Save with Codification and change to Unicode (UTF-8).

But i to need do this every time, in every cshtml file.

I can set the default Codification of CSHTML , as Unicode(UTF-8)??

Tnks!!

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title> - Teste_db</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
```

```
<body>
...

   <h2>View��  </h2>
...
</body>
```

Comment: Watch your http encoding response header

Comment: What does it mean that you found some cshtml files in Entity Framework?!? Entity Framework is an ORM and would not have anything to do with cshtml files.

Comment: sorry not is Entity Framework. here the full path C:\Users\desenvolvimento\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc\1.0.0-rc1-final\Templates\ViewGenerator

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan In View\Shared\layout.cshtml the head have >> <meta charset="utf-8" />

Comment: No offense, but can you please re-write the question, use correct grammar, spell check, and try to be a little more clear on the issue? I want to help, but the question is asked so poorly I cannot. Do this and I will be happy to help.

Comment: @TravisTubbs i try. LOL my english is bad.

Comment: all, good. Your edit helped a lot. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem!!!

I found the default .cshtml files from MVC.

The files is in C:\Users\USER_NAME.nuget\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc\1.1.0\Templates\ViewGenerator\

I edited them with notepad++,  changed the format to UTF-8, now i can put a especial caracteres like çéá...

Tnks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The default encoding for cshtml files should be UTF-8 anyways. If it is not, some other tool messed up your files.

The VS addon [fix-file-encoding](https://vlasovstudio.com/fix-file-encoding/) lets you select which encoding should be used depending on the file type.

As a side note, add `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` to the `<head>` of your HTML5 files so they are rendered correctly.

Comment: Patcheider I try but dont work. I put the html in the post.